# Why isn't my stylesheet page working when using handlebars(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, css, handlebars.js, stylesheet

When working on a handlebars demo, I am noticing that the stylesheet does not show up when viewing the page. I have provided links to the code and the live page below. Does anyone know why the stylesheet isn't working?

The code is here:
https://github.com/sutri001/DA670/tree/master/week7_handlebars

The live page is here:
http://67.205.184.187:1000

Answer (score 3):

Your rendered page *does* have the `link` tag that references the stylesheet you're looking for. What's happening is your server is throwing a 404 when a request is made for the stylesheet.

Looking at the code for your express server, I see you're telling express to serve files staticly from the `public` directory (good)... but you don't have a `public` directory, and even more your `css` directory is located outside of such a place.

**My advice is** to move your `css` *directory* into a new `public` directory (so you'll have `public/css/style.css`). That should resolve your issue.

---

Also, remember that it's the *browser* that's handling your `link` tags, not the server! That means browsers are currently trying to go to `http://yoursite/../../css/style.css`. Thankfully your browser understands how to handle this, but this is definitely not what you want.

Your `link` tag's `href` attribute should be set to `/css/style.css` because, from the browser's perspective, that's where the stylesheet is located.

Comment: i agree with you